# Legacy VSTO add in deactivated in Outlook 2016

Tags: vb.net, outlook, com, vsto, outlook-addin

I've inherited care for a legacy Outlook add in, triggered by an issue reported by an end-user, stating that the add-in isn't activated anymore.

**What I know**

We have an old custom add-in:

- Written in .NET 4 Client Profile
- As a VSTO project
- Written in VB.NET

It worked fine on Outlook 2010, the user's recently been updated to 2016.

**Symptoms**

- After installation, loading Outlook takes much longer
- You have to manually activate the add-in
- If you do, the menu/ribbon is loaded correctly
- On shutdown / restart of Outlook, the add in is inactivated again

It's config'd to be x86. I've tried switching that to x64, because I'm on a 64 bit OS, but then the addin just didn't load.

**What I've looked into**

I've googled a bit and found this link: [CRM for Outlook Add-In keeps disabling](https://support.boyum-it.com/hc/en-us/articles/208245778-CRM-for-Outlook-Add-In-keeps-disabling)

I think this quote describes what's going on:

> Microsoft has some security measures in place to prevent slow add-ins
>   from running inside Outlook. The issue is however that in many cases
>   add-ins without fault are mistakenly marked as slow and disabled by
>   Outlook, and if this is not immediately corrected when it first
>   happens, Outlook may permanently disable them with no easy way to
>   re-enable them.

I've researched with the help of an *infrastructure/network engineer* colleague to see if we can toggle the add-in to always enable, but no luck.

---

I've investigated eventviewer logs, I found this:

```
Outlook loaded the following add-in(s):

...
...

Name: AteamAddin
Description: AteamAddin
ProgID: AteamAddin
GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Load Behavior: 3
HKLM: 0
Location: file:///C:/Development/Deployment/AteamAddin.vsto
Boot Time (Milliseconds): 328
```

Followed by an entry with only my add-in on activating in Outlook, but with:

```
Boot Time (Milliseconds): 172
```

That's much slower than the second slowest, which loads in 47 milliseconds, but honestly, even 328 milliseconds isn't even that bad for a custom addin.

---

A weird thing is the empty GUID:

```
GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

But I don't know if it's important. I've tried adding a Guid attribute to my `ThisAddIn` class, but no effect.

**Question**

What can I do to have Outlook 2016 accept the custom add-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application needs two folders to move mails to, so it checks / creates it on startup of the add-in. It looks like Outlook 2016 is more restrictive in what is allowed. Checking these folders likely takes longer than Outlook allows, so the add-in is deactivated.

I moved the checking and creation of these folders to whenever a user opens any of the forms. That way it's way later in the process and that works without issue.

Answer (score 1):

The load time looks good, I don't see anything strange there. Instead, I'd suggest making sure no exceptions are fired at runtime. Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the `Startup` event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the `Startup` event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2019) article.

Also, I'd recommend making sure all the required prerequisites were included to the add-in package.

Comment: How can I find out these requirements? Also, are there any logs (outside Eventviewer) that Outlook logs where I can see -why- my addin was disabled?

Comment: issue has been resolved, see my answer. Thanks for the assistance.